# Are there behavior genetic models for multinomial outcomes?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, genetics, variance-decomposition

I am thinking of the standard behavior genetic model of decomposing the variance in an outcome variable into ACE components.

I will have outcome variables of different kinds: linear, dichotomous, ordinal and multinomial. The first three I think I can deal with in some way, but not the multinomial variable.

Comment: What is the standard behavior genetic model? Most people here will not have a biology but a statistics background so they may not be familiar with this.

Comment: I am thinking of the ACE model, the structural equation model for estimating variance components A (genetic), C (shared environment) and E (non-shared environment).

Comment: Phenotypes of two twins (P1 and P2) are regressed on their respective latent variance components.